# Can I change a column from Choice to Text without data loss?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, choice-field, single-line-of-text

I want to change a SharePoint Choice column to a single(or multi)-line text, Can I do this without data loss?

What will happen to the data if I change it?

Comment: Yes, you can change choice to single line of text column without any loss. Just to make sure it will work, you can create a test list in your site & try the same in test list from your side.

Comment: Is this single selection choice field or multiple selections choice field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my research, If you are using single selection choice column, you can change choice column to single line of text column without any loss.

---

If you are using multiple selection choice column and trying to convert it to single line of text, you should see the confirmation pop up like:

[image]

When I clicked on "Save" button, I was not able to see the column data in list view:

[image]

But, when I open the edit form of list item, I can see the previous selected choices semicolon separated like:

[image]

---

**Note**: Just to make sure it will work at your end, you can create a test list in your site & try the same in test list from your side.

Answer (score 0):

Others have given useful answers but I have also discovered something:

you can change just about anything to text, including choice and the data will remain HOWEVER it may become hidden, if this is the case you need to hit "edit column", scroll down to more options and scroll down again and hit column validation, where you will likely see a whole bunch of nonsense, if you delete that the raw data that was held there will be available as text